# Datastage 9.1 - Read Multiple Files from a Folder and Split It Based On Name

Tags: datastage

I'm using DataStage 9.1, I expose you my task to find some best practices to start.

I need to read multiple csv files (all files) from a folder and swich the execution of the ETL in ten different jobs based on the last two character of the filename. Then my questions are:

The aim is: the file fileXX will be used as input for the ETL which will fill the tabXX, the fileYY the tabYY and so on..

1) How to read multiple files from a folder? 
2) How to switch jobs based on filename, or better how I can develop parametric job based on the alue of the input file name?

Could someone give me some input to start in the best way my work?

Answer (score 1):

1) For reading multiple files from you can use an external source and put a as a parameter a command that returns the files in the folder (ls if you're using UNIX or Linux in your datastage server)
2) To switch maybe you could use a bunch of filters or you could use multiple external sources one for each type of files for exemple if you're using UNIX or Linux you can make one external source with a parameter "ls path_of_the_directory/*XX.csv" and one with "ls path_of_the_directory/*YY.csv" as ls supports wildcarding, but I don't know if there's an equivalent to it in Windows

Comment: Hi I'm using Linux, but is there a way to perform such steps only using DataStage job? Is there a way to spilt the execution based on the file name?

Comment: Sorry I'm late but what I described is only using DataStage jobs then the job execute the shell command

Answer (score 1):

To read multiple files, you can create paramiterised file name. Consider your file name is FileXX ( take XX part as a parameter For eg. lets take paramter Var, so your file name will be File#Var#). Pass on the values to that parameter. You can do the same formula for Table as well. If you want to read all the files together then you may need to pass the values in ini file / you may need to create different source stages.

Answer (score 1):

Based on Random's original answer and Linux functionality;

External file stage using an external command similar to

```
grep -Han ^ /pathtofile/#pFileMask# > /dev/null

H = file name
a = forces reading of file as text
n = line number
```

This will generate 3 columns
FileName
LineNumber
AllData

You can then pass through to a transformer and filter out to individual links by filename or a separate file mask

Then you will have to separate the AllData column out, easiest way is by using the column import stage and a schema file for each of your file types.

Again, this is based off Random's original answer so any credit should go to him/her

Hope this helps